# Index isn't crawling paragraph fields

Tags: search, paragraphs

I have the following index and paragraph fields checked off as my paragraph field is called *field_content*. However when I do a search for something inside these paragraph fields. I'm not getting any results.

Is there a way to debug if it indeed is crawling my paragraph fields? Or is there another setting that I might be missing since I'm attaching the paragraph entity to the Basic Page content type. Does Search API even go into the sub-entity and crawl that aswell?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside from just checking off those boxes on the search api page, you have to also mark it in the View exposed filter that your creating as seen below:

[image]

Comment: Yes make sure you click this! You don't necessary have to index the paragraphs themselves, if your paragraphs are all bundled into the one field, you can just index that field.